# como usar un metodo de laravel en un request

Tags: html, laravel, ajax, json

como puedo hacer esta validacion dentro de la clase request, esta parte corresponde a un metodo del controlador

```
public function store(vendedorrequest $request)
    {
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'nombre' => 'required',
            'nombre.required'=>'Rellena el campo nombre',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
       }

    }
```

este es el request donde quiero aplicar el metodo make, pero solo se hacerlo directamente desde el controlador

```
  public function rules()
    {

        return  [
            'documento'=>'required|numeric|unique:vendedores,documento',
            'correo'=>'required|email|unique:vendedores,correo',
            'nombre'=>'required',
            'direccion'=>'required',
        ];
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Validación en Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation)

#### Crear un Form Request

> Los form request son clases de request personalizadas que contienen lógica de validación. Para crear una clase de form request, use el comando CLI Artisan `make:request`:

```
php artisan make:request StoreVendedor
```

> La clase generada se ubicará en el directorio `app/Http/Requests`. Si este directorio no existe, se creará cuando ejecute el comando `make:request`. Agrega las reglas de validación al método de `rules`:

```
/ **
 * Obtenga las reglas de validación que se aplican al requst.
 * *
 * @return array
 * /
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'documento'=>'required|numeric|unique:vendedores,documento',
        'correo'=>'required|email|unique:vendedores,correo',
        'nombre'=>'required',
        'direccion'=>'required',
    ];
}
```

> Entonces, ¿cómo se evalúan las reglas de validación? Todo lo que necesita hacer es inyectar el request en su método de controlador. El form request entrante se valida antes de que se llame al método del controlador:

```
/ **
 * Almacene los datos del Vendedor en la Base de Datos.
 * *
 * @param  StoreVendedor  $request
 * @return Response
 * /
public function store(StoreVendedor $request)
{
    // El request entrante es válido ...

    // Obtén los datos de entrada validados ...
    $validated = $request->validated();

    // haz algo aquí con los datos validados ...
}
```

> Si la validación falla, se generará una respuesta de redireccionamiento para enviar al usuario de regreso a su ubicación anterior. Los errores también se mostrarán en la sesión para que estén disponibles para su visualización. Si la solicitud era una solicitud AJAX, se devolverá una respuesta HTTP con un código de estado 422 al usuario, incluida una representación JSON de los errores de validación.

---

Puedes sobreescribir el método `failedValidation` si quieres personalizar la respuesta:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {

    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));

}
```

Ten en cuenta que tendrás que importar esas clases en el form reques para poder usarlas agregando estas líneas arriba:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que lo hice de esa forma por que cuando le coloco el request que creo con mis reglas de validacion me retorna a la pagina donde estaba cosa que funciona. pero yo necesito es que me devuelva un json para poder recibirlo en ajax

Comment: yo lo que quiero es recibir los mansajes de error en forma de json por eso lo hice de esa manera

Comment: Si envías una solicitud ajax, y la validación falla, va a devolver una respuesta HTTP con un código de estado 422 al usuario, incluida una representación JSON de los errores de validación, como dice en el último párrafo.

Comment: ya hice la prueba cuando ejecuto el form y hago un return de la variable validated simplemente me redirecciona y no me muestra ningun mensaje

Comment: es que lo que se me olvido mencionar es que no estoy usando ajax todavia solo quiero hacer un return del json con los errores y devolverlos

Comment: para una idea mas claro coloco la imagen de que si esta funcionando el problema es que yo quiero tomar las reglas del request que cree y no del que tengo en el controlador

Comment: Elimina la validación del Controlador.  Como ya está escrito en la respuesta, **Todo lo que necesitas hacer es inyectar el request en tu método de controlador. El form request entrante se valida antes de que se llame al método del controlador**. También actualicé la respuesta por si lo que quieres es personalizar la respuesta en caso de que la validación falle.

Comment: disculpa pero donde coloco ese metodo failed validation ?

Comment: En el form request, debajo del método `rules` puede ser